# How to enter decimal value in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a project where I have a decimal price, and I did let visual studio 2015 scaffold the project for me, but when I enter a price and I enter something like 10.55, it's invalid, also tried 10,55 etc. 
I can add add whole numbers like 10, and when I post that to the db and I a take a look at the index page the price is listed as 10,00. But when I try to edit as well to be 10,55 it tells me it's invalid.

This is the property:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
    [Range(0.01, 999.99,ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 0.01 and 999.99")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: Tried both, it dosen't accept anything if I add decials.

Comment: it's decimal , it has to work with 10.55 .

Comment: @Viva The value '1.10' is not valid for Price.

Comment: What culture are you using? In your application and in the browser?

Comment: @SteenTøttrup I have not speficed a culture, so I assume it swedish, sv-SE.

Comment: @foobar Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue atm, my property looks the same as yours.